# Java 2D Graphics API that can provide zooming facilities?

Tags: java, graphics, zooming

Actually, my work is based on displaying a diagram in the screen, and while zooming in/out, the information in the diagram becomes more/less (just like Google Map).

May anyone guide to a 2D Graphics API that can allow me zoom in/out my drawings in Java easily?

I have used `Graphics2D` with `AffineTransform`, but showing more/less details in the diagram is somehow difficult using these stuff. I actually mean that Java Graphics API does not help in showing more/less details, positioning them, changing their size, etc. I have to write code for everything and every change in my design requires too much effort to modify my code.

Comment: Well, that's a general question. Can you explain *somehow* why it is difficult to maintain your code?

Comment: Thanks @BinkanSalaryman for your response. I actually mean that  Java Graphics API does not help in showing more/less details, positioning them, changing their size, etc. I have to write code for everything and every change in my design. That's why I am seeking for a better API that can organize my work well.

Comment: You seem to be referring to what sometimes is called "Semantic Zooming". It can indeed be challenging to properly maintain the information (basically: at **which** zoom level, **which** details should be visible). I'm not aware of a pure Java2D toolkit for this (although I partially implemented some simple forms of semantic zooming here and there).

Comment: Thank you @Marco13, this seems very useful topic. I will read about this concept.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) where the diagram class representing the diagram with all the details is your model, the displayed image is your view and the zoom buttons/wheel are your controllers.

Here are some quick ideas:

You could have some method that builds the rendered image always using the same "internal" size, with more or less details depending on the zoom required and then use the `AffineTransform` to enlarge it (which is the easiest way to zoom an image as far as I know). Each time the zoom is changed this method is invoked passing the new zoom and the image is rebuilt.

If this is not feasible (e.g. because the coordinates of the additional information are not easy to compute on a small image) you can try the other way round: first build the basic image, enlarge it, then use the method to incrementally add new informations to this image. You can even cache the images built from smaller zoom values to speed up the process.

Comment: Thank you @Antiphon0x for your useful description. This seems to be interesting. I will try model my work using the MVC pattern. But, I wonder if there is an API that can apply MVC principles to provide better zooming mechanisms.